# Deploy на GH Pages, через workkflows GH Actions

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-actions

Пытаюсь создать рабочий процесс для Gh Actions.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При регистрации  указывал и email и имя в github.

**файл .yml**

```
name: Deployment Application
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  deploy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
    - name: Get repository code 
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      run: | 
      run: npm ci
      run: npm run deploy
```

**выполняемые скрипты**

```
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d public",
 "predeploy": "tsc && sass src/sass:public/css"
```

Comment: Не очень понятен ваш вопрос, чтобы заработал [github actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart), нужно создать файл `*.yml` в директории `.github/workflows` в вашем проекте. Можете показать содержимое этого файла? [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1482921/edit) его в вопрос.

Comment: "Vadik файл создан, но выскакивает подобная ошибка

Comment: Посмотрите пример использования `actions/checkout@v3` [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73683452).

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикладывайте текстовую информацию в виде текста, [а не скриншотами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120). Тогда другим участникам сообщества не придется перепечатывать ваш код, чтобы воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @Vadik исправил

Comment: Возможно, git config ... нужно выполнять в том же шаге, что и npm deploy? У меня в одном скрипте выполняется сначала git config ..., потом git push, и отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если пишу перед выполнением команд в деплое - выскакивает ошибка fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Comment: Кажется, у вас получился невалидный yaml-файл. Нужно больше отступов перед `git config...`. Будьте внимательны с отступами в yaml-файлах.

Comment: @Vadik с этим я уже разобрался, он не дает теперь задеплоить gh-pages

Comment: Обновите ваш вопрос. Сейчас в вашем вопросе [невалидный](https://www.yamllint.com/) yaml-файл. Старайтесь задавать вопрос по одной конкретной проблеме. Сейчас не совсем ясно, какая у вас проблема решена, а какая осталась. Возможно, по новой проблеме стоит задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @Vadik Вопрос был и создан по одной текущей проблеме, workflow падал с ошибкой, так как гитхаб не признавал меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно пригодится кому-то рабочее решение.

**Получение и добавление ТОКЕНА**

> Settings(настройки профиля) > Developer settings > Personal access
> tokens > Tokens (classic) > Generate new token ( Generate new token
> (classic) > (x[repo] и x[user]) даем название и Generate token.

- Не закрываем вкладку и копируем токен!

> Settings(настройки репозитория) > Secrets > Actions > New Repository
> secret

- Names (Имя произвольное для вашего секрета/токена) | Secret (вставляете полученный токен).

> Add secret

**Yml файл**

```
name: Deployment Application
# Триггеры на которые будет реагировать экшн (пуш и ручной запуск).
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]
# Тут хранится ваш секрет/токен (смотря какое вы дали ему название)
env: 
  TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
jobs: 
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
     - name: Get repository code
       uses: actions/checkout@v3
     - name: Include repository, build & deployment
       run: |
          git config user.name "Ваше имя"
          git config user.email "Ваш эмейл"
          git remote set-url origin https://git:${TOKEN}@github.com/имя_акаунта/репозиторий.git
          # Установка зависимостей
          npm ci
          # Сам деплой
          npm run deploy -u "ваше-имя <ваш-эмейл>"
```

**.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d папка_откуда_забирать_файлы_на_деплой"
```

}

**Или**

```
npx gh-pages -d папка_откуда_забирать_файлы_на_деплой -u "ваше-имя <ваш-эмейл>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите команды, которые устанавливают `user.name` и `user.email`, прямо в конфигурационном файле `*.yml`.

Вот базовый пример использования экшена [**actions/checkout@v3**](https://github.com/actions/checkout):

```yaml
name: Example Checkout Action
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
          date > generated.txt
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m "generated"
          git push
```

Comment: Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/deployment.yml#L6
You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 6 - сейчас вот такая ошибка с текущими изменениями

Comment: Вообще. Если я правильно понял. Гитхаб не признает меня и говорит ты кто, че ты тут добавлять собрался. И просит верифицироваться. Но как не пробовал все не то. Если с официальной документации. Он что-то пишет, что ключи uses и run  не могу идти вместе, что то такое